# Emscripten not generating a source map

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to compile my Emscripten module with a source map, so I can debug in the browser.  But I'm not getting a .map file generated.

I'm compiling the source file with -g option as described in the documentation (https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html):

```
em++  -Werror -g -std=gnu++14 -o obj\MyFile.cpp.o -c ..\src\MyFile.cpp
```

And then linking with -g4 and -gsource-map:

```
em++ -s USE_WEBGPU=1 -s ALLOW_TABLE_GROWTH=1 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[addFunction] -s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_NAME=MyFramework -s TOTAL_MEMORY=1048576000 -DEMSCRIPTEN=1 -g4 -gsource-map obj\MyFile.cpp.o -o MyFramework.js
```

But I only get a js file and a wasm file, no map file.

Any ideas what issue could be?  I get the same results if I output a HTML file rather than a JS module.  This is on Windows with this Emscripten version:

```
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 2.0.13
clang version 13.0.0 (Cswircachegitchromium.googlesource.com-external-github.com-llvm-llvm--project 8d7cbcf582c5c7bc08a9de7f31fed63bf2687127)
Target: wasm32-unknown-emscripten
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on the WebAssembly Discord server.  The problem was my version of Emscripten, needed to be 2.0.17 or higher.